# JavaScript how to realtime update the DOM by using an Array?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm not sure whether the KnockOut can do this or not, but what I want is to use the pure JavaScript Variable (let's say an 'Array') as the source of an DOM Element (let's say an 'UL').

When I update the Array entries, I want the 'UL' to be reflected in realtime manner. Of course:

- I don't want to use timer kinda things
- And I only want to use pure JavaScript Array. (Not an Angular Object or whatever)

Is it even possible please?

Comment: no `pure` javascript object even knows about DOM, let alone interacts with it the way you want. You'll have to write some code instead

Comment: Knockout can do that by using _observables_. If you're already using Knockout you can simply wrap your array in Observable and bind it in your template.

Comment: @Jaromanda I think he means binding to a plain JavaScript array, not that the binding itself needs to be done with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using array.push to update your array, write a setter that will update both the array and the list.

```
var list = document.querySelector('#myList'),
    model = [],
    update = function update(value) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        model.push(value);
        item.textContent = value;
        list.appendChild(item);
    };
```

Comment: I think he wants to properly bind the array, so that changes to the array will be reflected automatically in the UI.

Comment: If he wants to use the things knockout provides, the question is very misleading.

Comment: I agree, the question could use a rewrite. ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for helping. But how do I then write the question in other way please. :3

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to use the knockout.js binding methods, then use the Observable binding as Ted says. You can find the syntax in the knockout documentation. If you don't want to use knockout, you'll have to write everything yourself, similar to my code. If none of these options does what you want, specify what you mean with 'using pure javascript array'.

Comment: As long as I can access the JS Array from anywhere, like from jQuery also, then I'm ok with any library or framework. But I believe Angular is too much for this purpose only. And also frameworks like Angular can not access the JS Array, or, the objs inside Angular can't be accessed from outside. (vice versa) So may be KO? Can KO allow my Array to be still accessible globally? As I said, I want to work through the normal JS Arrays.

Comment: Follow Teds suggestion and just keep the array in a variable as well, so you can still access it directly if needed. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html